# Buttons width to fill up window width

Tags: javascript, html, css

The App will start with 2 buttons in the footer initially.
Depending on user interaction with the app, a third button may need to be inserted/shown. And later it may need to be hidden/removed depending on some user selections form other parts of the app.

Button text is to be centred horizontally inside each button and the footer will need to be fully covered by the buttons except the tiny vertical division for spacing.
The footer in my code has an undesired blank space on the right.

What is the best way to solve this?, hopefully with as much css as possible and the rest with javaScript "I a guessing". Thanks

[image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
    color: turquoise;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

section {
    margin-top: 40px;
}


footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

footer > button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;

}

header, footer {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
</section>

<footer>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >NO</button>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >EXTRA</button>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">YES</button>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want all three buttons to take up the same space then this will work for you:

```
footer > button {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    width: 31.33%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
    color: turquoise;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

section {
    margin-top: 40px;
}


footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

footer > button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
</section>

<footer>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >NO</button>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >EXTRA</button>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">YES</button>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```